# Creating a multi user Chat application in core php

Tags: php, chat

Hi Im building a User relationship management application in php, here in this application we would require a multi user chat application in php, since im new to chat based application if any one have a chat application in core php please do share with me if would be very helpfull

Comment: Just use google - php chat script free

Comment: I did tried everything every chat application what i do get in google its filled with bugs, and im unable to fix all those bugs

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an exact answer to your question, but could be useful.

Building a multi-user chat system from scratch on bare PHP, is a lot of work. You might want to look into php frameworks that save you at least half of the work. 
  Have a look at **Laravel Framework**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6

  It can integrate 3rd party services, example Pusher(https://pusher.com/) to run a multiple channel chat.

   There are a lot of tutorials on youtube.com or https://laracasts.com/ (Laravel dedicated resource center and forum) that can help you get a chat up and running within an hour or two.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you integrate [socket.io](https://socket.io/) in your application.